# PHP, ftp_mkdir always returns false

Tags: php, ftp

I have a site which is using FTP to transfer uploaded files to a CDN. This site has been running fine for about a year. Now all of a sudden it wont upload the files correctly.

They are being uploaded, just not in the right place (users root dir /var/www).

Anyone have any idea why the `ftp_mkdir` function would stop working?

There have been no permission changes and the permissions for the folder on the CDN are set to 777 and the owner/group are set to the only user on the server (apart from root)

```
ftp_login($conn, '', '');

ftp_pasv($conn, true);
$mk = ftp_mkdir($conn, '/var/www/folder/subfolder/' . $id); // returns false
```

It uploads the file fine, it just won't create the directory for it
and since it doesn't create the directory, it doesn't `cd` to it so just plonks the file in the current directory.

Comment: ftp_mkdir returns false if the server returns a problem. So you need to look what changed at the server. It could be that the server got changed and will not accept absolute path in mkdir any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I had used up the 20GB of disk space. Only found the error when trying to create the folder as root, which showed the error.